# Use JSON data with a colon in Jquery Ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I have json that looks like the following although this is only the beginning of it, not the whole lot.

```
{"ns1:AmplifyResponse":{"AmplifyReturn":{"Topics":{"Domains":null,"TopTopics":[{"Topic":{"Name":"loo","Value":5.00},"
```

I am doing this jquery ajax call to get it, again its trimmed:

```
 $.ajax ({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'ajax/openampcheck.php',
    dataType: 'json',
    async: true,
    data: {"inputtext": inputmaintext},
    success: function(msg){
$('#oaresult').html(msg.ns1:AmplifyResponse.AmplifyReturn.Topics.TopTopics[1].Topic.Name);
....
```

in Chrome console this given me an error... Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token . 
for the last line, which seems to be something to do with the colon here ...

```
ns1:AmplifyResponse
```

if i wrap it in quotes though, i.e.

`$('#oaresult').html(msg."ns1:AmplifyResponse".AmplifyReturn.Topics.TopTopics[1].Topic.Name)`;

i then get this error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

How should I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('#oaresult').html(
              msg["ns1:AmplifyResponse"] // you have to use object["prop"] here
              .AmplifyReturn
              .Topics
              .TopTopics[1]
              .Topic.Name);
```

or

```
$('#oaresult').html(msg["ns1:AmplifyResponse"]["AmplifyReturn"]["Topics"]["TopTopics"][1].["Topic"]["Name'});
```

Comment: Thanks, is: msg["ns1:AmplifyResponse"]["AmplifyReturn"] etc the correct way they should be done as best practice?

Comment: In my opinion, don't bracket and quote unless needed. Extra characters reduce readability.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$('#oaresult').html(msg["ns1:AmplifyResponse"].AmplifyReturn.Topics.TopTopics[1].Topic.Name);
```

Comment: Thanks very much, marked you as correct as you answered 30s before codeparadox!

Comment: Thanks, but you should give it to him. He beat me by 7 seconds. He answered at 16:01:38Z and I answered at 16:01:45Z. :)